# Disproving $\oplus$ETH by reducing $\oplus k$-SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses to planar graph with $o(m^2)$ vertices?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, sat, counting-complexity, planar-graphs

In [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30881) and its answer, they discuss about reducing CNF-SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses to a (problem on) planar graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|$ as small as possible. It is said that the best known reduction has $|V| = m^2$, and that if a better reduction with $|V| \in o(m^2)$ is found, that would refute ETH.

---

There is a reduction from $\oplus k$-SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses to $\oplus$VERTEX COVER where the output graph $G=(V,E)$ is planar and has $|V| = 51(k+1)nm$. Such reduction clearly meets the $|V| \in o(m^2)$ requirement when $k$ is a constant and $m$ is superlinear in $n$.

---

> **Question**
> Can the same line of reasoning made within the linked question be applied here in order to refute $\oplus$ETH, or am I missing some important detail?

Comment: What is $\oplus$ETH?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2275.pdf, $\oplus$SETH is mentioned. From page 3: "Formally, $\oplus$SETH asserts that, for all $\epsilon$ < 1,
there exists a (large) integer $k$ such that $\oplus k$-SAT cannot be computed in time $O(2^{\epsilon n})$". Unless I'm wrong, such definition is to $\oplus k$-SAT as the SETH is to $k$-SAT. Then, I've imagined that if $\oplus$SETH was introduced, then so was $\oplus$ETH... Is it the case that, while $\oplus$SETH exists as a conjecture, there is no such thing as $\oplus$ETH?

Comment: I didn’t say that it didn’t exist. I simply asked what it was. “Exists” can mean anything between “someone mentioned it in passing in one obscure paper”, and “it is widely known in the field”.

Comment: Why do you assume that $n = o(m)$? To my understanding, for the purposes of ETH (not sure about $\oplus ETH$) we should assume that $m = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: @Laakeri: Maybe you're right, but then why in the linked question and its answer there is no such limitation? They pose no constraints on $m$. I imagine they implicitly refer to the Sparsification Lemma, but even in such case there is something unclear to me: suppose they take a CNF with unbounded $m$ and reduce it to a subexponential number of CNFs having $m' = \Theta(n)$, then they turn each of such CNFs into a planar graph to take profit of its sublinear treewidth. Even if this is their reasoning, why they write $|V| \in o(m^2)$, being $m$ the number of clauses of the original formula? ...

Comment: @Laakeri: ... In order to claim the disproval of ETH they should have written $|V| \in o(n^2)$, no? In which case it wouldn't have been surprising and I wouldn't have raised this question. On the other hand, it might be that in the linked question they assume, since the very beginning, that the original formula already has $m = \Theta(n)$: but again, if that's the case, why writing $|V| \in o(m^2)$, and why using the $m$ variable at all rather than simply saying that the original formula had $cn$ clauses for some constant $c$?

Comment: I do not understand why they use $m$ instead of $n$ in the linked question either... Probably they assume that $n < m$, which makes their argument correct, and is probably fair to assume. Assuming that $n = o(m)$ is much stronger than this.

Comment: A disproval of $\oplus ETH$ would also be a disproval of ETH, because there is a randomized reduction from NP to UP.